# Copying data from OpenCV Mat to Surface via NDK produces small error.

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

I am working on an application that will process camera frames through a native method and then posting the processed result into Java TextureView's Surface. I had been [looking on this application](http://nezarobot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/android-surfacetexture-camera2-opencv.html) as a reference and implemented the code into mine. However, I am getting a weird green stripe on one of the side which I assume is a difference between surface's width and buffer's stride. I am trying to work out a solution ,but no success. Can anybody give me some help with that?

Here's the code of native call:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_android_cols2svlc_receiver_utils_JNIHelper_surfaceTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jint srcWidth, jint srcHeight, jobject srcBuffer,
                                                                jobject dstSurface, jstring path_, jint savefile) {
    const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(path_, 0);

    // Code

    LOGE("bob path:%s saveFile=%d", str, savefile);

    uint8_t *srcLumaPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(srcBuffer));

    if (srcLumaPtr == NULL) {
        LOGE("blit NULL pointer ERROR");
        return NULL;
    }

    int dstWidth;
    int dstHeight;

    cv::Mat mYuv(srcHeight + srcHeight / 2, srcWidth, CV_8UC1, srcLumaPtr);


    ANativeWindow *win = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, dstSurface);
    ANativeWindow_acquire(win);

    ANativeWindow_Buffer buf;

    dstWidth = srcHeight;
    dstHeight = srcWidth;

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(win, dstWidth, dstHeight, 0 /*format unchanged*/);

    if (int32_t err = ANativeWindow_lock(win, &buf, NULL)) {
        LOGE("ANativeWindow_lock failed with error code %d\n", err);
        ANativeWindow_release(win);
        return NULL;
    }

    uint8_t *dstLumaPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(buf.bits);
    Mat dstRgba(dstHeight, buf.stride, CV_8UC4,
                dstLumaPtr);        // TextureView buffer, use stride as width
    Mat srcRgba(srcHeight, srcWidth, CV_8UC4);
    Mat flipRgba(dstHeight, dstWidth, CV_8UC4);

    // convert YUV -> RGBA
    cv::cvtColor(mYuv, flipRgba, CV_YUV2RGBA_NV21);

    // Rotate 90 degree
    // rotateMat(flipRgba, 2);

    LOGE(" ------- DATA -----------  \n dstWidth: %d   stride: %d ", dstRgba.cols, buf.stride);

    // copy to TextureView surface
    uchar *dbuf;
    uchar *sbuf;
    dbuf = dstRgba.data;
    sbuf = flipRgba.data;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < flipRgba.rows; i++) {
        dbuf = dstRgba.data + i * buf.stride * 4;
        memcpy(dbuf, sbuf, flipRgba.cols * 4);
        sbuf += flipRgba.cols * 4;
    }


    // Draw some rectangles
    line(dstRgba, Point(dstWidth/2, 0), Point(dstWidth/2, dstHeight-1),Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    line(dstRgba, Point(0,dstHeight-1), Point(dstWidth-1, dstHeight-1),Scalar(255,255,255 ));

    LOGE("bob dstWidth=%d height=%d", dstWidth, dstHeight);
    ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(win);
    ANativeWindow_release(win);

    // Release
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path_, str);

    //Ret
    return env->NewStringUTF("abc");
}
```

...and this is what I get as the output:
[image: Imgur]

I also printed all sizes to check for differences:

```
03-08 10:45:55.234 9681-9706 E/NATIVE_IMPROC:  ------- DATA -----------  
                                               dstWidth: 1152   stride: 1152    dstHeight: 1920
```

Answer (score 0):

If **srcBuffer** is coming from **camera2** image reader, it probably comes in [YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888) format, which has a header that can specify non-zero stride, and offsets to Y, U and V planes. Actually, Y, U and V frames may belong to separate **ByteBuffer**s, but usually the camera manufacturers are too lazy.

Comment: So the stride explicitly can cause this small green stripe on top? The black area under the surface view is not a problem. When I rotate the image 90 deg CCW it comes on the left side and the surface fills the whole screen.

Comment: It's hard to tell what effect the wrong interpretation of input format can have. On some devices your code will crash, because the U plane and V plane are not necessarily continuation of Y.

Comment: True, I might give it a try.